# How to avoid returning handles to object internals - Item 28 Effective C++

Tags: c++, effective-c++, dangling-pointer

Item 28 of Effective C++ says `avoid returning "handles" to object internals`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176751/avoid-returning-handles-to-object-internals-so-whats-the-alternative) shows how to design your code to do exactly that by thinking about encapsulation in order to avoid accidentally exposing the internals of your class.

My example involves a data array and since memory is an issue I'd like to avoid using `std::vector` (and the Boost library).

Using an array here's a very simplified version of my code:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int size) : data_(new int[size]) {
        // Populate with data just for the example
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            data_[i] = i;
        }
    }

    // I know that this isn't good practice
    int* const get_data() const {
        return data_;
    }

    ~Foo() {
        delete[] data_;
    }

private:
    int* data_;
};

int main(void) {
    Foo* foo = new Foo(10);
    int* const data = foo->get_data();
    delete foo;
    // data now dangles which is bad!
    return 0;
}
```

I understand that using `const` with `get_data()` doesn't make it safe. If I was using a vector I could copy it like the example question above, but since I'd like to avoid this I was wondering how best to design my class to avoid this potentially dangerous situation?

Comment: `std::vector` has *very little* overhead over a raw array, and it's much safer and easier to use.

Comment: If I don't mistake, "Effective C++" says also that you should use `vector` in any cases, except you **exactly** (!!!) sure, that it will act worse then another container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programming and software design is a constant "choice of one thing over another". If you REALLY can't afford using `std::vector`, and you need to expose data to the client-code using your class, then so be it. Document why it is so, and make sure that it's reviewed over time - it may be that when your new model of hardware that has 8MB of RAM instead of 2MB will be able to use the extra 4 bytes that a `vector` takes over your plain pointer.

Or write an accessor function:

```
int& Foo::operator[](int pos)
{
   // Add checks here to ensure `pos` is in range?
   return data[pos]; 
}
```

Now you don't have to return the pointer at all...

Answer (score 1):

The one way in your situation is to use smart pointers. I'd prefere [shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). Here's how you can modify your class to avoid problems you raise:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int size) : data_(new int[size]) {
        // Populate with data just for the example
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            data_[i] = i;
        }
    }

    // I know that this isn't good practice
    std::shared_ptr<int> const get_data() const {
        return data_;
    }

    ~Foo() {
        //delete[] data_;
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<int> data_;
};

int main(void) {
    Foo* foo = new Foo(10);
    std::shared_ptr<int> data = foo->get_data();
    delete foo;
    // data still good )) // --now dangles which is bad!--
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If she even can't tolerate the overhead of the pointer in std::vector, I wonder how she can stay with the idea of shared_ptr overhead and duplication of data ...

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia - hmmmm.. didn't think about it... but I will ))

Answer (score 0):

If you really wish to avoid using std::vector, you can implement approach similar to one used by some winapi functions.

```
size_t get_data(int* data_ptr, size_t& buffer_size)
{
if(buffer_size < sizeof (data_)
{
buffer_size = sizeof(data);
return 0;
}
//You could you memcpy for ints here
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            data_ptr[i] = i;
        }
return sizof(data_);
}
```

Thus requiring caller to provide memory to store data and care about allocations of that memory.
Thru it should be reinvention of what std::vector already would do with much less safety.
Also you should check [Rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) to avoid problems when you will start using your class more extensively.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of cases where returning pointers is perfectly acceptable, even the array was actually contained in `std::vector`; e.g. using external APIs and when copying data is not appreciated.

I don't see the danger since you're not programming for monkeys. User of the class ought know. But I added function to query the size of the data. That is for safety.

```
extern "C"{
void foobar( const int *data, unsigned int size );
}
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(unsigned int size) : size_(size), data_(new int[size]) {
        // Populate with data just for the example
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            data_[i] = i;
        }
    }

    unsigned int get_size() const{return size_;}
    int* const get_data() const {
        return data_;
    }

    ~Foo() {
        delete[] data_;
    }

private:
    int* data_;
    unsigned int size_;
};

int main(void) {
    Foo* foo = new Foo(10);
    int* const data = foo->get_data();
    foobar( data, foo->get_size() );
    delete foo;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

considering even the standard library has `get_native_handle()` on classes like `std::thread` I wonder who between the standard library or EC++ was wrong!

Effective C++ is a set of guidelines you simply can't apply them all in any context. It's a "moral" book. Don't treat it as "legal". If you are required to expose the data just do it.

After all who deletes a pointer to your internal data (after getting it through a getter) is also doing a "bad thing", since he's acting destructively on something does not belong to him.